# Angular / Typescript Class Getter property not working

Tags: angular, typescript, getter

I've a class as shown below

```
export class Story {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    storyText: string;
    utcDate: string;
    get displayDate(): string {
       const today = new Date();
       const postDate = new Date(this.utcDate);
       const td = today.getTime();
       const pd = postDate.getTime();
       return ((td-pd)/1000)+'ms';
    }
}
```

HTML view is shown below

```
<span>
   <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   {{story.displayDate}}
</span>
```

Here, the html code block is inside and ngFor loop as `*ngFor="let story of stories"` and stories is an array of type Story , `stories: Story[];`
But its not displaying anything . No error also. What am I doing wrong here? Will this work like this without an explicit setter property? Or should I create a setter property and set the value manually?

edit: 
below my script that populate the story array and the service function

```
loadData() {
this.storyService.stories()
.subscribe(
data => {
  const response = <Story[]>data.message;
  this.stories = response;
},
error => {
    alert('error');
});
```

}

```
    stories() {
          return this.http.get<Result>(this.baseUrl + '/story/list/', this.httpOptions);

 }
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve]; how do you create the story object? Also I'm surprised TypeScript isn't throwing an error pointing out that your getter doesn't return a string.

Comment: "Will this work like this without an explicit setter property?" Yes it will. Nothing is wrong for me in your example

Comment: My guess is that story isn't actually an instance of Story: you probably get these stories as a JSON response to an HTTP request. But HTTP will never, ever create instances of any of your classes.

Comment: you should define it like ```public story = new Story ;``` in your app.component.ts

Comment: FYI, I'm inside an ngFor Loop ...... *ngFor="let story of stories". Here stories is an array of Story type. @JBNizet .@jonrsharpe  . Updating question with this

Comment: That is almost irrelevant. What you need to provide is the code creating these Story instances, i.e. the code where you have `new Story()`. Or better, a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. If you don't have `new Story()` anywhere, then you're never constructing any Story instance.

Comment: why not just remove the `get` and call `{{ story.displayDate() }}` instead? this is also better OOP

Comment: @scipper that wont work. It shows error as method unknown

Comment: well, then I hook up with jonrsharpe: more code please

Comment: Please check the updated code. Hope @jonrsharpe this much is enough

Comment: I still don't see any new Story() anywhere. So you're not creating any Story instance (unless storyService does that, but you chose not to post its code). You're just telling TypScript here: "trust me: data.message is an array of Story". But it's not. It's probably (since you didn't post the service code) an array of plain old JS objects unmarshalled from JSON.

Comment: @JB Nizet got it. So I've to explicitly call Story() for each of my array item to work with Getter right ???

Comment: You aren't actually creating a class instance, giving a type hint **does not** cause any casting or conversion. This is what @JBNizet already said; you need to map to `new Story` for an accessor to work.

Comment: Updated question again. So you guys please direct me with a best option to initialize all these array elements as type Story. I dont want to loop through the array and create object for each element.

Comment: *I dont want to loop through the array and create object for each element.*: Too bad, because that's exactly what you **must** do if you want to keep the existing design.

Comment: Is there any mapper available in TypeScript so that I dont have to initialize objects like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your getter wont work unless you create a new instance. 
Also when you are putting stories: Story[], you are only telling that it is safe to assume Stories will contain properties in Story class. Typescript wont that there is a getter.

Since you are inside ngFor, I suggest using a Pipe.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'displayDate'
})
export class DisplayDatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any): string {
    const today = new Date();
    const postDate = new Date(value);
    const td = today.getTime();
    const pd = postDate.getTime();
    return ((td-pd)/1000).toString();
  }

}
```

then in your template make slight modification like this.

```
<span>
   <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   {{story.utcDate | displayDate }}
</span>
```

Comment: Yea, I think I should go with this instead of creating object for each of my array items. Thanks

Comment: Yes, creating instance for each object wouldn't be a good solution.

Answer (score 7):

This is because when you cast in Typescript, you don't get the methods.
So imagine you have this :

```
const data = {
    id: 1;
    title: 'foo';
    storyText: 'bar';
    utcDate: '01-01-2000';
}

const story = data as Story;
// OR
const story = <Story> data;

console.log( story.displayDate ); // Wrong, because the method doesn't exist
```

So instead, you need to create a new object

```
const story = new Story(data.id, data.title, data.storyText, data.utcDate);
console.log( story.displayDate ); // Will work !
```

But that mean you must have a `constructor` and you need to loop on your array of stories.